# Why sometimes php return http header like plain text HTTP/1.1 200 OK where it should return only json?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, http, chat

I have dynamic website which is send request to server per 50second if user use chat it will be per 1 second but sometime  php  return text like below  ?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 23 Nov 2016 03:04:36 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: d=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
Set-Cookie: s=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
Vary: Origin
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=74
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

2
[]
```

My php part only get datas from mysqli and use echo json_encode();In the example as you see it returned json like [] but it also return HTTP/1.1 200 OK ... like things.What is the problem?is that about host,server problem,hosting, or reason is I send so much request?

Comment: So what does the PHP file look like....?

Comment: @Darren php file just send query to mysqli server and return result;in my example [] is result but problem is what is others?

Comment: @Darren I use ehost hosting is that possible reason is hosting?because when I use hostgator I have not such a problem but it was VPS and this one is shared hosting

Comment: @IbrahimHasanov check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Comment: @Vamsi I edited my question and gave more information,and I gave more details also sorry for bad question but I fixed it

Comment: @Vamsi but I dont know how can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the Content-Type of your response adding in php, before the json_encode call:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

In this way you are sure the response is sent by php as application/json

Comment: php just check if statements and then create sql query and echo json encode result